# React native ListItem image url passing variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I wanted to pass some variable into my image url for avatar but this is not working it seems:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
 <ListItem
      title= {item.name}
      subtitle={
        <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
          <Text style={styles.ratingText}>Price: {item.price}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ratingText}>Stock: {item.stock}</Text>
        </View>
      }
     avatar={{ uri: 'https://test.com/${item.ver}/${item.cid}.jpg',}}
    />
)
```

This is for rendering my `ListItem` and I need those variable to get different avatar picture for different items but this is not working for me. Any other way of doing this?

Comment: You need to use backticks instead of a single quote:
avatar={{ uri: \`https://test.com/${item.ver}/${item.cid}.jpg\`,}}

Comment: errm what does that means?

Comment: A single quote is this: '
A backtick is this: `

Answer (score 1):

Here is a preview for your requirement. https://codesandbox.io/s/3v0qn6j0zp . ES6 comes up with a new type of string literal, using the back-tick as the delimiter. These literals do allow basic string interpolation expressions to be embedded, which are then automatically parsed and evaluated..

```
    let fb = "facebook";

    <Image
        source={{
          uri: `https://${fb}.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png`
        }}
      />
```